# How do I restore a snap to pristine condition

Tags: snap

How do I restore a snap's state to pristine condition?

A snap was working fine, then crashed, and now it perpetually crashes.  Something in it's state has changed and I'd like to restore it to pristine - as if it were just installed.  How is this done?

Specific problem

I installed a snap (remmina) and was able to use it for a short period if time.  I then had a crash (not sure whether that was server/client fault), and now I am unable to connect to that particular device again.  It is likely that the software state has become indeterminate.

So I'd like to return it to pristine state.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that snap was updated? Have a look at `snap info remmina` and you will see when it was updated and compare it with time you noticed problems.

If that was the case, you can revert to previous version  easily with `snap revert remmina` which will revert to previous version. Or you can play with `revert  --revision=` parameter

Comment: No update occurred (I had only installed it for the first time moments before).  Obviously I could work around by uninstalling and reinstalling (which I ended up doing), but my question stands as I am interested if there is a way to reset it (my nearest analogy is "Clear Data" for an Android app - which restores it to "just installed" state).